# Drawing new shapes in addition to existing ones in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw two shapes. Shape 1 is drawn straight away and shape 2 in a second after shape 1. My problem is that shape 1 disappears when I draw shape 2.

Inside my constructor I have:

```
    mCurrentTick = 1;
    invalidate();

    scheduleDraw();
```

Then

```
private void scheduleDraw() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mCurrentTick++;
            invalidate();
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Inside onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    drawShape(canvas, mCurrentTick);
}
```

And drawShape is:

```
private void drawShape(Canvas canvas, final int tick) {
        switch (tick) {
            case 1:
                draw1(canvas);
                break;

            case 2:
                draw1(canvas);
                draw2(canvas);
                break;
```

Draw methods look like this:

```
private Canvas draw1(Canvas canvas) {
    mPath1.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    mPath1.moveTo(mTopPointA.x, mTopPointA.y);
    mPath1.lineTo(mTopPointE.x, mTopPointE.y);
    mPath1.lineTo(mTopPointD.x, mTopPointD.y);
    mPath1.close();

    canvas.drawPath(mPath1, mPaint);
}

private void draw2(Canvas canvas) {
    mPath2.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    mPath2.moveTo(mTopPointA.x, mTopPointA.y);
    mPath2.lineTo(mTopPointD.x, mTopPointD.y);
    mPath2.lineTo(mTopPointC.x, mTopPointC.y);
    mPath2.close();

    canvas.drawPath(mPath2, mPaint);
}
```

EDIT:

Seems to be working if I remove setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

Answer (score 0):

When you invalidate it clears the canvas and draws all again.  So for the case where tick is 2 if you want it to draw both I would swap places in the switch statement and not have a break for case 2, that way it will "fall through" to case 1.

Comment: Good point, thanks. However I don't think that fixes the problem cause in case 2 I'm drawing both shapes again. Actually i'm just investigating this further and I *think* my problem is in Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD